# custom luatex format file

Tags: fonts, luatex, libertine, format-files

I have to process a big number of files with the same preamble.  Therefore I try to build a custom format file.  The biggest »time eater« is font loading in lualatex, so I try to load the fonts in the format file.

I copied lualatex.ini and modified it slightly, so that it loads my preamble just before dumping:

mylualatex.ini:

```
% [...]
% the next line is added by me
\input mypreamble.tex

% restore \dump for derived formats (mylatex, etc) that might use it
\let\dump\DUMP
\let\DUMP\undefined
\dump
```

mypreamble.tex:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[libertine={Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle}]{libertineotf}
```

When I try to use the generated format file, I get an segfault:

```
> luatex \&mylualatex.fmt        
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.1-2011061416 (rev 4277) 
 restricted \write18 enabled.
[3]    4569 segmentation fault  luatex \&mylualatex.fmt
```

TIA,
 Marcus

Comment: I think this has been mentioned on the luatex mailing list before, but lacks an entry on the bug tracker. I doubt that the font information will be stored in the format file.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, sad to hear.  I think I'll go with pdftex, which is fast enough for my purpose.

Comment: @PatrickGundlach: I think your comment is an answer.

Comment: @PatrickGundlach: http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=746

Answer (score 7):

The issue with `luatex` crashing has been fixed in LuaTeX SVN. See http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=787

It still won't help with font loading though.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [currently known error](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=746) that has been encountered and reported by [Martin Schröder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5763/martin-schroder). So you are currently out of luck.

Besides that, I am pretty sure (well 99.9% sure) that your fonts won't be dumped into the format.