# Precompiled header with lualatex and unicode-math

Tags: luatex

Consider the following:

preamble.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\def\preambleloaded{Precompiled preamble loaded.}
```

main.tex

```
\def\ifundefined#1{\expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax} \ifundefined{preambleloaded}
\typeout{PRECOMILED PREAMBLE NOT LOADED}\input{preamble} \else
\typeout{\preambleloaded}
\fi

\begin{document}
test test test
\end{document}
```

Now I use `lualatex -ini -job-name="main" "&lualatex preamble.tex\dump"` via the command line with the result of, apparently, an unfinished run (the corresponding logfile ends with

```
Beginning to dump on file main.fmt
 (format=main 2014.9.11)
24193 strings using 403578 bytes
919997 memory locations dumped; current usage is 243&455843
22307 multiletter control sequences
\font
```

).

Subsequently the use of `lualatex -shell-escape "&main main.tex"` results in an error of the form of

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013062821 (rev 4627)
\write18 enabled
Could not undump 1 4-byte item(s): <fd:3>: unexpected end of file
```

The use of, e.g., Asana Math leads to the same error.

I have an up-to-date MikTeX System and I use Cambria Math routinely with unicode-math, so I guess the font cannot be installed completely wrong.

Am I doing something wrong?
To be honest, I'm completely clueless.
Any help greatly appreciated! :-)

Comment: I doubt that you can dump a font in the format. See e.g. the comments here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46672/custom-luatex-format-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer font dumping works at least in some cases. Commenting out the unicode-math related part above and replacing it with `\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={MinionPro-It},BoldFont={MinionPro-Bold},BoldItalicFont={MinionPro-BoldIt},SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic},Ligatures={TeX,Common},Scale=MatchLowercase,Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{MinionPro}` results in a correctly working fmt file as well as a correct pdf output in the end.

Comment: I have to partly correct myself -- only the standard Minion Pro font works, neither the bold nor the italic or the oldstyle figures work. Does this have to do with the loading of pdftex.map that seems to occur by loading the generated fmt somehow?

Comment: @John try updating your Luatex binary. Élie’s [fix](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=746) was applied some time ago. If it still fails afterwards, there might be another bug that should be reported to the devs.

Comment: @phg The error persists with `LuaTeX, Version 0.79.1 (TeXLive 2014/W32TeX)` I still get `Could not undump 1 4-byte item(s): <fd:3>: unexpected end of file`.

Comment: @phg Still the same error with Version beta-0.79.1 and Miktex. Is this functionality planned for the future? It would be a convenient way to speed compilation times enourmously up I think.

Comment: @John Better ask these questions on the mailing list. Anyways,
fonts are already cached as Lua bytecode so the bulk of the
work of internalizing a font is already done at this point.